# Access an variable from outside angular controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-controller

I'm using [timetable.js](http://timetablejs.org/) together with an angular router and firebase for the backend. My code looks like this:

That is the html file that angular routes to:

```
<div class="timetable" ng-init="initTimetable()"></div>
```

That's the file where I handle all my functions from that router:

```
myApp.controller('myController', function($scope) {

    $scope.initTimetable = function() {
        var timetable = new Timetable();
        timetable.setScope(8, 14); 

        timetable.addLocations(['Place 1', 'Place 2', 'Place 3']);

        timetable.addEvent('Homework', 'Place 1', new Date(2016,9,10,11,45), new Date(2016,9,10,12,30));

        var renderer = new Timetable.Renderer(timetable);
        renderer.draw('.timetable');
     };
});
```

What I'm now trying to do is to run that **timetable.addEvent()** function outside that controller.

I hope somebody understood, what I'm trying to do and can help me.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you  caling timetable.addEvent() from inside of angular (service, controller, directive)?

Comment: What I tried was to just call the timetable variable from another js file, which of cause didn't worked out.

Comment: you can use **timetable.addEvent()** in directive by passing values from dom

Comment: You are doing way too much in your controller  Put the logic for the timetable in a service (so it can be used by other modules and controllers throughout your application), and then leverage that service from this controller.  The controller should then only be leveraged by the view.  Trying to do otherwise will very likely lead you to an unscalable mess.

Comment: @ojuskulkarni That is not working either, because I need to get my values of firebase. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: @btberry Thanks I will try that!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example of how you could use angular to do this.  All I did was create a quick and dirty `fiddle` that puts your code in a directive.  In the directive I added an `addEvent` button that for now just creates the same event each time.  You would need to update this to take in the inputs required to add an event (i'll update the fiddle later today to show you how you could do this).

Fiddle showing all of this:  http://jsfiddle.net/ncapito/kkxphvg7/

**Directive Definition**

```
  angular.module('myApp').directive('timetable', [function() {
    return {
      scope: {
        locations: '='
      },
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      controller: TimetableController,
      template: '<div><div class="timetable"></div><button ng-click="addEvent()">Add Event</button></div>',

    };
  }]);
```

**Directive Controller**:

```
 function TimetableController($scope) {
    var timetable = new Timetable();
    var renderer = new Timetable.Renderer(timetable);

    init();
    $scope.addEvent = addEvent;

    var idx = 3;

    function addEvent() {
      var newLocation = 'Place ' + ++idx;
      $scope.locations.push(newLocation);

      //add if new
      timetable.addLocations([newLocation]);
      timetable.addEvent(
        'Homework' + idx, newLocation, //need to add a ui to collect this
        new Date(2016, 9, 10, 11, 45), //need to add a ui to collect this
        new Date(2016, 9, 10, 12, 30) //need to add a ui to collect this
      );

      render();
    }

    function init() {
      timetable.setScope(8, 14);
      timetable.addLocations($scope.locations);
      timetable.addEvent('Homework', $scope.locations[0], new Date(2016, 9, 10, 11, 45), new Date(2016, 9, 10, 12, 30));

      render();
    }

    function render() {
      renderer.draw('.timetable');
    }

  }
```

Comment: Thanks for your Answer, I will take a look at it tomorrow.